# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/javatuples/Unit

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, tuples, executable-jar

I have imported the javatuples-1.2.jar in Eclipse project. I did this to run the Java Tuples Unit class program. The following is the code:

```
 package mynewpackage;
 import org.javatuples.Unit; 

 class Mynewclass2 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 
    Unit<String> u 
        = new Unit<String>("This is demo text!"); 

    System.out.println(u); 
   } 
 }
```

But, getting the following error on running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/javatuples/Unit
    at mynewpackage.Mynewclass2.main(Mynewclass2.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.javatuples.Unit
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Under the references, I can easily see that the tuples jar file is successfully added. However, the following is the project directory, jar in references, error, and the entire program in Eclipse.

[image: Eclipse Project Directory with Java Tuples]

How can I fix the issue and run Java Tuples programs correctly?

Comment: how exactly are you running `Mynewclass2.main()` - are you launching it from the "mynewproject" or are you launching from another project (eg. "demo") referencing the "mynewproject" project?

Comment: I am running the class from the same project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have java 11 in place...

When I (try to) reproduce your setup:

1. My eclipse (Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), Win_64_jdk_11.0.2) asks me for "module name" and adds `src/module-info.java` after creation of a "Java Project",  ... then download and add `lib/javatuples-1.2.jar` to build path.
2. When I *try to* use/import it in my code (main class) - compilation error, and auto-correct proposes me to add "javatuples" module to module-info:

click-clack:

#### myproject/src/module-info.java

```
module myproject {
   requires javatuples;
}
```

After that the program is already runnable, but **Eclipse warns**:

```
Name of automatic module 'javatuples' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.
```

To **fix** this, you can run (from command line):

```
myproject>jar --file=lib/javatuples-1.2.jar --describe-module
No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

javatuples@1.2 automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains org.javatuples
contains org.javatuples.valueintf
```

So, eclipse warning is already sort of nasty: **javatuples** is the "correct" module name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @xerx593! I still don't know how to fix it. Can you please make it simpler like in steps? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: get the latest eclipse!

Comment: This is the latest eclipse!

Comment: \*surprised\*! ..then - "no steps", "just": create the module-info.java file.

Comment: Bingo! You're a genius! I tried your steps and it worked!

Comment: nah, for "genius" I'd claim harder problems! :) But glad that it helped, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on javatuples-1.2.jar > Build path > Add to Build Path .

**NoClassDefFoundError** is an error that is thrown when the Java Runtime System tries to load the definition of a class, and that class definition is no longer available.

Comments are Welcome.

Comment: Right Click on javatuples-1.2.jar > Build path  - Here, I can only see three options:  Remove from Build Path, Migrate Jar File, Configure Buil Path. Therefore, I think it is already added to Build Path.

Comment: "remove from build path" means "it is already there;" @AmanChawla

Comment: Yes! This is what I mentioned. Anyways, thank you for the answer. Xerx593 reply worked for me!